# How do I solve this problem on application of derivatives? Please help.

Tags: derivatives

How do I solve this?
For the curve $x^{m+n}=a^{m-n}y^{2n}$, where a is a positive constant and $m,n$ are positive integers, prove that the $m$'th power of subtangent varies as $n$'th power of subnormal.

Comment: The first step is to understand what the problem asks. "subtangent" and "subnormal" are not terms that are commonly used these days. I am taking their definitions from Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is to understand what the problem asks. "subtangent" and "subnormal" are not terms that are commonly used these days. I am taking their definitions from Wikipedia.

Let $P = (u,v)$ be a point on the curve $C: x^{m+n} - a^{m-n}y^{2n}=0$. The curve is singular at $(0,0)$, and since the problem involves the tangent line, implicitly, it is being assume that the statement is made for points other than $(0,0)$; therefore, let's assume $P \ne (0,0)$.

The tangent line to $C$ at $P$ is
$(m+n)u^{n+m-1}(x-u)  - a^{m-n} 2n v^{2n-1}(y-v) = 0 $.
The subtangent is $T-u$ where $T$ is found by looking for the point $(T,0)$ where the tangent line intersects the $x$ axis, i.e.: $T$ solves
$(m+n)u^{n+m-1}(T-u)  - a^{m-n} 2n v^{2n-1}(0-v) = 0$.

The normal line to $C$ at $P$ is
$a^{m-n} 2n v^{2n-1}(x-u)  + (m+n)u^{n+m-1}(y-v) = 0 $.
The subnormal is $N-u$ where $N$ is found by looking for the point $(N,0)$ where the normal line intersects the $x$ axis, i.e.: $N$ solves
$a^{m-n} 2n v^{2n-1}(N-u)  + (m+n)u^{n+m-1}(0-v) = 0 $.

Solving for $(T-u)$ and $(N-u)$, after some algebra, using the fact that $u, v$ are not arbitrary, but lay on the curve $C$, on gets $(T-u)^{m} = g (N-u)^{n}$ where $g$ is a constant that depends on $n, m, a$, but not on the point $P$, which is probably what is meant by "varies as" in the statement of the problem.